# How to force a specific software to use proxy?

Tags: networking, windows-10, proxy

I want to use a Tor SOCKS proxy on some programs (e.g. Android Studio) but not all.

I'm a Windows 10 user. How can I do that?

Comment: TOR can never be truly effective when run from a box configured to only be partially private. With TOR its all or nothing. It is almost impossible to get all apps to honor proxy configuration (especially DNS queries) so the only alternative is to force ALL traffic through the tunnel.

Comment: If a program doesn't support it natively, you need something like `socksify`.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to run the software in a virtual machine. If your Windows 10 is a Pro version, it comes with Hyper-V, or you may use other vm-software.

For installing a virtual machine, look here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyperv_on_windows/quick_start/walkthrough_create_vm

However, note this: *Unless you're running a volume-licensed version of Windows, you need a separate license for Windows running inside a virtual machine. The virtual machine's operating system is independent of the host operating system.*

As Android Studio also runs on mac and Linux, you can just install Linux in the virtual machine.

Comment: Please explain how that would achieve the desired behavior, step by step.

Comment: I updated my answer.

Comment: That still doesn’t explain how the program’s traffic will end up in TOR.

Comment: You just set the entire traffic of the vm togo through TOR. I don't know much about the socks/proxy situation, but if you say you can make all or no traffic go through the proxy, I gave you the idea of running the software in a virtual machine, where all it's traffic is proxied. This is not a turn-key solution, just an idea to work on.

Comment: @Lenne I already try that and it didn't help much. I have only 8GB ram and I use 3GB for VM. the time it take to load was very high. Is there any way to use virtual network card?

Answer (score 0):

You can use some software like [Proxifier](http://www.proxifier.com).  This inserts itself into the Winsock 2 stack as a Layered Service Provider, and intercepts connections made by apps.  You can set which apps are intercepted, and configure them to connect out via a variety (even chain) of proxies.